# Regex return between

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code. Note the wild card is what I actually want. (please forgive the bad code before final refactor).

```
string findRegex = "{f:.*}";
Regex regex = new Regex(findRegex);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(blockOfText))
{
    string findCapture = match.Captures[0].Value;
    string between = findCapture.Replace("{f:", "").Replace("}", "");
}
```

What I dont like about the code is trying to get what is in between what I found, the double replace statements. Is there a better way?

**Additional: Here is a sample string**

```
Dear {f:FirstName} {f:LastName},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parens to group part of your match and extract it later:

```
string findRegex = "{f:(.*?)}";
Regex regex = new Regex(findRegex);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(blockOfText)) {
    string between = match.Captures[1].Value;
}
```

If you want exactly two matches (e.g. for your first-name last-name example), make two groups:

```
string findRegex = "{f:(.*?)}.*?{f:(.*?)}";
Regex regex = new Regex(findRegex);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(blockOfText)) {
    string firstName = match.Captures[1].Value;
    string  lastName = match.Captures[2].Value;
}
```

Comment: It appears the regex is capturing "Firstname} {f:Lastname" as one capture. I have added example to my post.

Comment: @Valamas: Ah, then you need a non-greedy match: `.*?`. I'm updating my post.

Comment: thank you for helping and adding to my white-belt regex skills, growing daily!

Answer (score 1):

Use groups:

```
string findRegex = "{f:(.*)}";
Regex regex = new Regex(findRegex);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(blockOfText))
{
    string findCapture = match.Groups[1].Value;
    // ... rest
}
```

Comment: It appears the regex is capturing "Firstname} {f:Lastname" as one capture. I have added example to my post.